# Add the line to an array with the given initials in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, text-files

There are more than 1500 textfiles and each file may have more than 10 lines. But let's say there are two files with 5 lines.

Assuming File1 contains:

```
gwvY ko qwxu hovY iksY qwxu ]
gwvY ko dwiq jwxY nIswxu ]
hukmI hovin jIA hukim imlY vifAweI ]
gwvY ko gux vifAweIAw cwr ]
gwvY ko jIA lY Piir dyh ]
```

and File2 contains:

```
shs isAwxpw lK hoih q iek n clY nwil ]
ikv sicAwrw hoeIAY ikv kUVY qutY pwil ]
gwvY ko ividAw ivKmu vIcwru ]
gwvY ko swij kry qnu Kyh ]   
hukmI auqmu nIcu hukim iliK duK suK pweIAih ]
```

and if someone searches for "g k" then the searching should begin from File1 to File2 and should pull up any line that contains 'g' as the first initial of the first word (in the line) and 'k' as the first initial of the second word (in the line) from both of the text files.

For instance, in this case the array should return:

```
gwvY ko qwxu hovY iksY qwxu ]
gwvY ko dwiq jwxY nIswxu ]
gwvY ko gux vifAweIAw cwr ]
gwvY ko jIA lY Piir dyh ]
gwvY ko ividAw ivKmu vIcwru ]
gwvY ko swij kry qnu Kyh ]
```

Because "g k" was the search word and the lines returned starts with the first and second letter of 'g' and 'k', respectively. 
I am not sure what is the best way and fastest way to approach to this problem. Anyone here can help me with this? I would really appreciate. Thank you.

Currently, I am using the following way.

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
String mLine;
for (int i = 1; i <=1500; i++){   //1500 Files, for-loop runs 1500 times.

try {
   reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(open("File"+i)));
   mLine = reader.readLine();    // Files are read one-by-one and then the lines are ready one-by-one

    while (mLine != null) {
    String[] array_line = mLine.split("\\s+");  //words in the line are separated by the space are collected in an array.

    // and search_word_arr is when the user enters "g k" the search_word_arr[0] = 'g' and search_word_arr[1] = 'k' and then the initial of the words in the line are checked.
    if((array_line[0].startsWith(""+search_word_arr[0])) && (array_line[1].startsWith(""+search_word_arr[1]))){
       arr.add(mLine);
    }
    mLine = reader.readLine(); 
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {

}
```

Comment: Are the files in one single directory?

Comment: Yes, they are just named as File1, File2, File3,...,File1000, etc.

Comment: Are you looking for something more efficient than using `s.charAt(0) == 'g' && s.charAt(s.indexOf(' ') + 1) == 'k'` (pseudo code!)?

Comment: Which java version? For fast execution it is suboptimal to work on the filesystem, but i guess it is not an option to put everything in a DB?

Comment: 1500 files, each (let's say 100 lines of 80 characters). 2 bytes per characters. That makes 1500 * 100 * 80 * 2 = 24,000,000 bytes, or 24 MBs, which is tiny. Why not read all the lines into a list in memory? You could even use two `Map<Character, List<String>>` to index all the lines by the first character of their frst and second word. Of course, if your program ends after a single query, that's not needed.

Comment: For file handling you can check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html for a start.

Comment: I have edited my question (provided the code). Please have a look.

Comment: Is there a reason why you start your loop counter at 1 ?

Comment: That's used to open the files. Since files are named as File1, File2, File3, etc. so in the code it just does "File"+i, where i is the counter from 1 to 1500.

Answer (score 1):

As always: Don't waste time on premature optimization.  If your current implementation is fast enough: just use it!

Here are a few suggestions I would try on your code if it turned out that it were not fast enough:

- This is not for speed but for correctness (and thus most important): Don't silently assume that your line has always at least two words.
- Don't use `split('\\s+')` but `indexOf(' ')` to find the first space character.  Then step forward until you find the first non-space character.  There is no need to process the line any further.  If you need to deal with lines starting with whitespace and other characters such as tabs, this will require some thinking to get correct.
- Reading each line as a string causes a lot of memory allocations and deallocations.  If you have many lines that match, you will need to allocate them sooner or later anyway but if your matches are sparse, you might gain something by opreating on re-used `char[]` buffers which is rather inconvenient since you'll have to do the scanning for newlines yourself now.  (Which might well spoil the gained advantage, if you implement it poorly.)
- Once you are thinking of your file as a long array of characters, memory mapped files might be faster and not more inconvenient.
- If you have more than one CPU: Use the *Pipeline* pattern to have one thread read in the data, n threads filter it (your program will probably be I/O bound so n = 1 will be appropriate) and one thread write the output.  This will also limit the amount of memory your program uses at any time so it will scale well.

Except for the last point, which is nice, all these optimizations will not make your software more maintainable.  So don't incorporate them easily if your current solution isn't actually too slow.